# Pyodbc error in Python How to fix connection

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I am trying to Connect to sql server database but I get this error:

```
 File "C:\Python37-32\SqlVersionpr_import.py", line 528, in proceed
with pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL 
Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password) as myDbConn:
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found 
and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

My code:

```
server = '***********' 
database = '*****' 
username = '***********' 
password = '***********' 
        
with pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password) as myDbConn:
     with myDbConn.cursor(as_dict=True) as cursor:
         cursor.execute(''' select * from empInfo where ssn = %s and storeid = %s ;''',(strLastSsn,stono))
         emp_rows = cursor.fetchall() or []
```

Comment: Check the list returned by `pyodbc.drivers()` to see what drivers are available to your Python app.

Comment: ['SQL Server', 'SQL Server Native Client 10.0']

Comment: Okay, so try using `SQL Server Native Client 10.0` instead of `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` as your ODBC driver name.